# Unable to run selenium standalone server

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to run selenium-standalone-server 2.47.1.jar through command prompt.

But I am facing this error.

```
C:\automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver>java -jar selenium-server-standalo
ne-2.47.1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/gr
id/selenium/GridLauncher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher. Program wi
ll exit.

C:\automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver>
```

Why am I getting this error?

I have JDK installed already(since I need to run netbeans).

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: It seems the error is about conflicting your JDK versions.

Comment: What JDK version do I need? The one I installed has this name jdk-6u10-windows-i586-p.exe. Its JDK 6 I think

Comment: And what is your selenium running/compiled version ?

Comment: Smruti, did you compile your project using 1.7 ?

Comment: You mean, the selenium-standalone-server version? Its 2.47.1. selenium-server-standalo
ne-2.47.1.jar @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: Actually, I am totally unaware of JAVA environment or platform. Can you explain what do you mean by 1.7?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88243/discussion-between-ss--and-smruti-singh).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` happens because the code was compiled with a higher version of Java than the one you're running it.

Version 51.0 of a class file corresponds to java 7

```
J2SE 8 = 52,
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

You need to upgrade your JDK from Java 6 to Java 7 or higher.

Comment: Worth noting that Java 8 also seems not to work with this file.

Comment: Yup, not working for me either! I had upgraded, but still having the same issue...

Answer (score 6):

Just download the last JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

It helps me resolve the problem on my mac 
the problem was 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

resolved by download and install
Mac OS X x64    196.89 MB   jdk-7u79-macosx-x64.dmg

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine tried to use selenium-java-2.48.2.jar where he got the same error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncher : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>   ```

I sent him an old version selenium-java-**2.44.0**.jar and now it works in his environment just fine.

Comment: In package.json  you can add: `"selenium-webdriver": "2.44.x"`